# How to build TreeView from Arraylist

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2, javafx

I'm looking for a solution how to build a JavaFX `TreeView` from an `ArrayList`. I have this `ArrayList` witch contains connection name, database server name and list of tables:

```
public List<ConnectionsListObj> connListObj = new ArrayList<>();

    public class ConnectionsListObj {

        private String connectionName;
        private String dbgwName;
        private String tableName;

        public ConnectionsListObj(String connectionName, String dbgwName, String tableName) {

            this.connectionName = connectionName;
            this.dbgwName = dbgwName;
            this.tableName = tableName;

        }

        public String getConnectionName() {
            return connectionName;
        }

        public void setConnectionName(String connectionName) {
            this.connectionName = connectionName;
        }

        public String getDbgwName() {
            return dbgwName;
        }

        public void setDbgwName(String dbgwName) {
            this.dbgwName = dbgwName;
        }

        public String getTableName() {
            return tableName;
        }

        public void setTableName(String tableName) {
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }        

    }
```

I need some kind of a loop which looks into the tree and generates tree using this code:

```
TreeItem<String> treeItemConnections = new TreeItem<> ("Connections");

        TreeItem<String> nodeItemDBGW = new TreeItem<>("DBGW 1");

        treeItemConnections.getChildren().add(nodeItemDBGW);

            TreeItem<String> nodeItemTable = new TreeItem<>("Table 1");

            nodeItemDBGW.getChildren().add(nodeItemTable);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeItemConnections);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(treeView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

The question is how I can make a loop which looks into the `ArrayList` and constructs the three? And also when I select on a node I want to get the type of the node.

Comment: if the database db1 had two tables your array list would have 2 entries is it ? (having the same database details but different table names ?)

Comment: one connection , one database with one table ?

Comment: This is just example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the ConnectionsListObj objects in the tree?  I think TreeView calls toString() on the objects for the text in each tree node so just return the string you want to show from ConnectionsListObj.toString().  Then when you get the selected item by calling `myTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` you get an instance of ConnectionsListObj which should have all the data you need.

Loops in java look like the following for your case:

```
for(ConnectionsListObj connection : connListObj) {
    nodeItemDBGW.getChildren().add(connection);
}
```

or...

```
nodeItemDBGW.getChildren().addAll(connListObj);
```